# Need a button to reset the scene in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I need to make a button that restarts the scene. i tried

```
func reset():
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed('reset'):
        get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

But this doesn't work- any advice? All i need is the button to reset the scene

Comment: And what did not work exactly? Your function did not get called? Your scene did not reset? You got an error?

Comment: I'd venture to guess nothing is calling the `reset` function. Edit: You can use a `breakpoint` or a `print` statement to verify if the function is getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, but you actually must have the code to be called for it to have any effect. Place your two lines of code within a node's (or autoload's) `_process()` function and it should work.